# How would I read and write encrypted XML files?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, encryption

How would I approach reading and writing encrypted XML files? I need a way to save the user's last entered values for a form, but I don't want them to be readable as plain text or XML.

Comment: Same as encrypting any other stream of bytes.

Comment: What would I use to do this?

Comment: database such as sql server

Comment: A whole sql database seems a bit unwieldy to save the values of 3 textboxes...?

Comment: or if you want it to be verry simple use session variable whith any type of text enrcyption

Comment: It's a windows form app, and I want it saved when the app closes

Comment: your question is unlcear you need to specify this kind of stuff right now it seems like you are aksing for a asp.net website

Comment: You don't even say what encryption method you want. Aes? Rot13?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. And I've never done any kind of encryption before. Something simple, I suppose.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, that edit was not appropriate. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a comprehensive collection of classes available at your disposable to secure XML data in `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml Namespace`.

Take some time to read the following articles MSDN articles:

- [How to: Encrypt XML Elements with Symmetric Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb7w85t6.aspx)
- [How to: Decrypt XML Elements with Symmetric Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229740.aspx)
- [How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-14)

If you visit the root node in the navigation menu on any of the articles linked you can view  more articles on XML security.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you could just save the users saved strings and then write just a regular XML file with the encrypted strings?

Here's an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)

```
public class Crypto
{
    private static byte[] _salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("o6806642kbM7c5");

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt the given string using AES.  The string can be decrypted using 
    /// DecryptStringAES().  The sharedSecret parameters must match.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plainText">The text to encrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="sharedSecret">A password used to generate a key for encryption.</param>
    public static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, string sharedSecret)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        string outStr = null;                       // Encrypted string to return
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;              // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

            // Create a RijndaelManaged object
            aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
            aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // prepend the IV
                msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
                outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
                aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return outStr;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypt the given string.  Assumes the string was encrypted using 
    /// EncryptStringAES(), using an identical sharedSecret.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">The text to decrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="sharedSecret">A password used to generate a key for decryption.</param>
    public static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText, string sharedSecret)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
        // used to decrypt the data.
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.                
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                // Get the initialization vector from the encrypted stream
                aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(msDecrypt);
                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
                aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    private static byte[] ReadByteArray(Stream s)
    {
        byte[] rawLength = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        if (s.Read(rawLength, 0, rawLength.Length) != rawLength.Length)
        {
            throw new SystemException("Stream did not contain properly formatted byte array");
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(rawLength, 0)];
        if (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
        {
            throw new SystemException("Did not read byte array properly");
        }

        return buffer;
    }
}
```