# how to encrypt xml file for security

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the entire xml file for security, including its nodes and values. I have done something but I am not sure if it is correct way to do it. And also I am getting a null exception during the runtime

```
Encryption scrty = new Encryption("arif");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:\\PROJELE\\XML\\Language.xml");
string tst = scrty.Encrypt(doc.InnerXml);
doc.InnerText = tst;  // "null exception" is thrown here************
doc.Save("D:\\PROJELER\\XML\\Language2.xml");
```

After encryption, how can I assign it encrypted text to doc? is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008090/how-would-i-read-and-write-encrypted-xml-files to me

Comment: no way. my question is not totally about security. it is about the writing back the encrypted text to xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> doc.InnerText = tst;

it means that your call

```
string tst = scrty.Encrypt(doc.InnerXml);
```

is returning null. Now show us the working of `Encryption.Encrypt` so that we can tell you why it is returning null, or diagnose it yourself.

and for encryption you can see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- doc element is null now
- tst is null
- or some encoding issues in tst (encrypted text)

Show us the encrypted text, or debug to see if anything is null